# Docker failed to start daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted [Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) ] armv7l

Tags: docker, debian

**docker.log**

time="2020-02-18T10:05:51.740757000+08:00" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded." storage-driver=overlay2
time="2020-02-18T10:05:51.747446000+08:00" level=error msg="AUFS was not found in /proc/filesystems" storage-driver=aufs
time="2020-02-18T10:05:51.758181000+08:00" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded." storage-driver=overlay
time="2020-02-18T10:05:51.990661000+08:00" level=error msg="Udev sync is not supported. This will lead to data loss and unexpected behavior. Install a more recent version of libdevmapper or select a different storage driver. For more information, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#storage-driver-options" storage-driver=devicemapper
time="2020-02-18T10:05:52.146274000+08:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit"
time="2020-02-18T10:05:52.146389000+08:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts"
time="2020-02-18T10:05:52.146445000+08:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find blkio cgroup in mounts"
time="2020-02-18T10:05:52.146504000+08:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
time="2020-02-18T10:05:52.146553000+08:00" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
time="2020-02-18T10:05:52.149506000+08:00" level=info msg="stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown" module=libcontainerd
time="2020-02-18T10:05:52.160535000+08:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
failed to start daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted

**docker version**

Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.6
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.16
 Git commit:        369ce74
 Built:             Thu Feb 13 01:40:25 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: cat /etc/fstab   none        /sys/fs/cgroup        cgroup        defaults    0    0

Answer (score 7):

I am on MX Linux 21.3. It is based on Debian.

In my case `cgroup` was already mounted (`mount` told me so, also validated in `df`), but running `sudo dockerd` still gave me the same error ("Devices cgroup isn't mounted").

What worked for me was to install a package called `cgroupfs-mount`.

```bash
sudo apt install cgroupfs-mount
```

After this, `sudo service docker start` worked.

Reference: https://www.gushiciku.cn/pl/gcx5

Comment: This solved the problem for me on MX Linux 23, based on Debian 12.1

Answer (score 3):

I have this literally bookmarked, and I go here every time I need to start docker on my netbooting Alpine. Single command to mount the cgroup pseudofs, w/o touching fstab:

```
sudo mount -t cgroup cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup
```

FYI: this may be also caused by your kernel not having cgroup support compiled in, but it's highly unlikely.